# Better way to write this particular function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm beginning my journey with JavaScript and programming in general.
Not having many developers around I could ask how to do this or do that
i'm learning by doing however I'd like some pro's to look around my code
and tell me how bad it is.

Any comments for a Noob will be appreciated. Thank you in advance!
I know there is probably zillion such classes but I want to learn from
scratch and not reuse someones code at this level of my knowledge.

this function returns colors in rgba(r,g,b,a) or rgb(r,g,b) format 
taking a value for each channel or a random value if "random" is a parameter for
an color channel:

`someColor = nutils.getNewColor(100,200,"random","random");`

will return a string in format:

`"rgba(100,232,0.12)"` or `"rgb(100,200,234)"` if no alpha is passed

Here is the code I wrote:

```
window.utils.getNewColor = function (rRange, gRange, bRange, alpha) {
    function rValue() {
                    return Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
                }

                if (!rRange == undefined || rRange == null || typeof rRange === 'string' && rRange == "random") {
                    rRange = rValue();
                }
                if (!gRange == undefined || gRange == null || typeof gRange === 'string' && gRange == "random") {
                    gRange = rValue();
                }
                if (!bRange == undefined || bRange == null || typeof bRange === 'string' && bRange == "random") {
                    bRange = rValue()
                }
                if (typeof alpha === 'string' && alpha == "random") {
                    alpha = Math.round(Math.random() * 100) / 100
                    return "rgba(" + rRange + "," + gRange + "," + bRange + "," + alpha + ")";
                } else if (typeof alpha === 'number' && alpha < 1) {
                    return "rgba(" + rRange + "," + gRange + "," + bRange + "," + alpha + ")";
                }
                else {
                    return "rgb(" + rRange + "," + gRange + "," + bRange + ")";
                }
            };
```

### UPDATE

After reading your comments I come up with a solution based on @KooilNic advise, however slightly modified to comprehend my lack of understanding ternary operations evaluation.

Here is the modified/updated code:

```
utils.getNewColor = function (rRange, gRange, bRange, alpha) {
    rRange = rRange || Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    gRange = gRange || Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    bRange = bRange || Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    if (alpha === undefined) {
        return "rgb(" + [rRange, gRange, bRange].join(',') + ")";
    } else {
        alpha = alpha && alpha < 1 ? alpha : (Math.round(Math.random() * 100) / 100);
        return "rgba(" + [rRange, gRange, bRange, alpha].join(',') + ")";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider replacing rValue with a function to include those conditional checks, like so:

```
function genValue(v) {

    if(v == undefined || v == null || v == "random") {
        return Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    }

    return v;

}

// and later:
rRange = genValue(rRange);
gRange = genValue(gRange);
```

That should reduce some code duplication.

Also consider reducing the places where you construct your result (`"rgb(" + ... + ")"` to one or two places.

### EDIT:

Some people are recommending code like `!rValue || rValue == "random"`.  Take care with this, as if you pass 0 in for rValue, you will get random colors.

Comment: Thank you! Will do and repost the result's.

Comment: notice that `v == undefined || v == null` is redundant. You can simply have one of them, if you don't use strict equal, because `undefined == null` is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this method very short [using short circuit booleans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) or in the case of `alpha` a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation). There's no need to reference `window`  in the method call. All the check for `undefined` or `null` are unnecessary. A declared value can be referenced. Within if statements, use `===` as equality [comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators), because that compares both compares value and type.

The shorter version of your method:

```
utils.getNewColor = function (rRange, gRange, bRange, alpha) {
    rRange = rRange || Math.round(Math.random() * 255;
    gRange = gRange || Math.round(Math.random() * 255;
    bRange = bRange || Math.round(Math.random() * 255;
    alpha  = alpha && alpha < 1 ? alpha : (Math.round(Math.random() * 100) / 100;
    return "rgba(" + [rRange,gRange,bRange,alpha].join(',') + ")";
};
```

Comment: Did you miss a `?` in the alpha line?

Comment: If I only knew what circuit booleans are ;-) I probably will. Gonna search for the definition right away. Thanks!

Comment: Koolinc, could you tell me in simple vocabulary how those assigment works? I don't get it.
`alpha  = alpha & alpha < 1  alpha : (Math.round(Math.random() * 100) / 100;`

Comment: @KooiInc great answer, clears a lot. Thank you for the links and for your expertise!

Comment: Hi PJJ, glad I could help. The `alpha = ` part uses a ternary operator, kind of a short `if`. Maybe this link is more clear: http://javascript.about.com/od/byexample/a/ternary-example.htm

Comment: @KooiInc: OK, reading about it right away, however your solution isn't considering a case where no alpha is passed ;) and keeps generating random alpha even if none is passed. Nothing serious though ;]

I don't get fully the ternary operators since it looks for me like Bitwise operators. 

I started playing with JS few days ago and previously I was doing same basics in Java(processing) and AS3.

Comment: I get the ? : part, however what exectly is this conditional statement evaluating here? `alpha & alpha < 1` in simple words? This is a Bitwise Operator, am I correct?

Comment: It *does* consider if none is passed, but the condition was a typo. Should be: `alpha && alpha < 1`. Corrected the answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @KooiInc: correct me if am wrong: statement reads, if alpha equals (bitwise comparison) alpha and is smaller then 1 = 0 or 1

Comment: You don't need to specify the comma in `join`, is the default delimitator: `[1, 2, 3].join()`

Answer (score 0):

The comparisons like this:

```
typeof rRange === 'string' && rRange == "random"
```

can simply be `rRange === "random"`, as `===` avoids the type conversion.

Creating a fn that encapsulates your test and random generation will shorten the code. The name/concept of this function isn't ideal, but it will work:

```
function randIfNull(val, maxRandVal) {
    if (val == undefined || val == null || val === "random") {
        return Math.round(Math.random() * (maxRandVal || 255));
    } else {
        return val;
    }
}
```

(NOTE: I think you have an `rRange == undefined ||` which equals `rRange != undefined`-- which will almost always evaluate to true. I changed this.)

Then the body of your function can be more simple:

```
rRange = randIfNull(rRange);
gRange = randIfNull(gRange);
bRange = randIfNull(bRange);
```

And then you can combine some of the code in your final statements:

```
if (alpha == "random" || (typeof alpha === 'number' && alpha < 1)) {
    alpha = randIfNull(alpha, 100);
    return "rgba(" + rRange + "," + gRange + "," + bRange + "," + alpha + ")";
}
else {
    return "rgb(" + rRange + "," + gRange + "," + bRange + ")";
}
```